# What is the name of this big tree?

Tags: identification, trees

This tree is very tall and huge, and has many branches. I want to know the name of it, and I need to know the basic features of it.

[image: Big huge tree]

Comment: @shirley It would help if you could tell us where in the world you are, and give an indication of your climate. A description of the leaves, flowers, fruits, etc. would also be useful.

Comment: hate to say it but that picture alone does not allow me to identify it.  As Niall C. says, location, more photos of a leaf or fruit...

Comment: agree with previous comment - this pic shows the growth habit, but not much else for ID

Comment: Shirley, if you can provide the additional information requested, please feel free to 'flag' to reopen. Thanks.